# git smudge filter failing on last file

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-filter

I'm trying to do something similar to what git-lfs does using filters.
Download .apk files from S3 on git checkout, but smudge filter is always failing on last file because of ([apply_filter](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.1/convert.c#L737) function i guess).

Configuration:

```
cat .gitattributes
    *.apk filter=custom-lfs -diff -text

cat ~/.gitconfig
    [filter "custom-lfs"]
    smudge = custom-lfs %f
    required = true
```

If the filter is required to succeed '(required = true)' git status report assertion error:

```
git.real: convert.c:1165: convert_to_git_filter_fd: Assertion `ca.drv->clean || ca.drv->process' failed.
```

If it's not required git status is showing 1 from 20 apks modified, always the one which is downloaded last.
S3 source apk and my local copy have the same checksum.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.1/convert.c#L1165

Was thinking to try out with 2.18.

Comment: What is `custom-lfs`?  What is it returning?  Is it returning a failure?

Comment: It's simple bash script curling S3 bucket dumping the file to cache folder then perform hash checksum on it and if checksum is correct, cat the file to be smudged into working directory. Does not fail, I did some tests removing the apk in question (19 apks) and again last one is showing modified, second test was with just a single apk same result. Hence something is messed up during the last invocation.

Comment: What's the return code?  It certainly sounds like git is interpreting a non-zero return code from your filter as a failure, which it told you directly when when you turned on `required = true`.

Comment: Made custom-lfs just do `cat ../file.apk` and ran some more tests.
Now i understand better what is going on.
Sometimes on git clone I get clean workspace sometimes 4-5 apks are shown modified not only the last one processed by smudge.
On checkout file meta is recored `(size ctime mtime etc.)` in git index.
Don't know why git does not like that index data for some files and on git status
`apply_filter` is called only for these bad files, but with `wanted_capability = 1`,
size in git index is reset to 0 only for them and are now shown as modified files.

Comment: I can clean my working tree by doing git reset --hard 5-10times, which invokes again
`apply_single_file_filter`.
Now Index meta`(ctime mtime and ino)` is different from initial one during git clone and git status is clean.
With `required=True` can't do git reset --hard too
`assert(ca.drv->clean || ca.drv->process); which is = assert(null || null);`
Exit code then is:
`Abort trap: 6`
`134`
I don't understand C to debug it more, planning to play around with git-fat.